# extend typescript type in react setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this

```
type fruitCode = 'apple' | 'banana'
interface fruitList {
  name: fruitCode
}

const [arr, setArr] = useState<fruitList[]>([])
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-xqcqz?file=/src/App.tsx:65-143

I want to add new string `fruitCode` when I do `setArr` but it doesn't make sense to alter `fruitCode` because the new string isn't a type of fruit. What should I do to `fruitList[]` to extend it?

Comment: Why don't just add to them fruitCode?
type fruitCode = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'melon' | 'any_other_fruit'. But if you feel unsure, just make type fruitCode = string

Comment: @MuhammadIrvanHermawan because fruitCode is used elsewhere also. I can't add 'car' into fruitcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extend `fruitList` type (eg: `otherList`)

```
type fruitCode = 'apple' | 'banana'

interface fruitList {
  name: fruitCode
}

// add this type
interface otherList extends fruitList {
  name: string
}
```

2. use `otherList` in `setState`

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState<otherList[]>([])
```